# Segmentation fault (core dump) in C?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

This program basically search for the string in a file, and then produce the output based on the options provided.

For example, on the command line,

> cmatch -i hello helloworld.txt

I keep getting the segmentation fault, even if I comment out all the printf statement. But I'm new to C and I can't find any inappropriate pointer here.. Help?

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int exit_status = EXIT_SUCCESS;

bool checkIfMatch(char *string, FILE *file) {

    while (true) {
        char buff[1024];
        fgets(buff, 1024, file);
        if (buff == NULL)
            break;
        if (strcmp(string, strstr(buff, string)) == 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;

}


bool checkIfMatchIgnoreCase(char *string, FILE *file){
    while (true) {
        char buff[1024];
        fgets(buff, 1024, file);
        if (buff == NULL)
            break;
        if (strcasecmp(string, strstr(buff, string))== 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;

}

void printLines(char *string, FILE *file){
    while (true) {
        char buff[1024];
        fgets(buff, 1024, file);
            if (buff == NULL)
                break;
            if (strcmp(string, strstr(buff, string)) == 0)
                printf("%s",buff);
        }
}

void printLinesWithNumber(char *string, FILE *file){
    int ln;
    for(ln=1;;ln++) {
            char buff[1024];
            fgets(buff, 1024, file);
            if (buff == NULL)
                break;
            if (strcmp(string, strstr(buff, string)) == 0)
                printf("%d: %s",ln,buff);
        }
}

typedef struct options {
    bool ignore_case;
    bool filenames_only;
    bool number_lines;
} options;

void scan_options(int argc, char **argv, options *opts) {
    opts->ignore_case = false;
    opts->filenames_only = false;
    opts->number_lines = false;
    opterr = false;
    for (;;) {
        int opt = getopt(argc, argv, "iln");
        if (opt == EOF)
            break;
        switch (opt) {
        case 'i':
            opts->ignore_case = true;
            break;
        case 'l':
            opts->filenames_only = true;
            break;
        case 'n':
            opts->number_lines = true;
            break;
        default:
            exit_status = EXIT_FAILURE;
            fflush(NULL);
           fprintf(stderr, "%s: -%c: invalid option\n", 
                "cmatch.c", optopt);
            break;
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    options opts;
    scan_options(argc, argv, &opts);
    char *stringToMatch = argv[optind];

    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=argc-optind-1;i++){

    bool matched;
    FILE *file=fopen(argv[optind+i],"r");
    if(opts.ignore_case) matched=checkIfMatch(stringToMatch, file);
    else matched=checkIfMatchIgnoreCase(stringToMatch, file);

    if(matched){
        if(opts.filenames_only) printf("%s\n",argv[optind+i]);
        if(opts.number_lines) printLinesWithNumber(stringToMatch, file);
        else printLines(stringToMatch,file);
    }
    }

    return exit_status;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to find out where it occurs

Comment: how to use a debugger? print statement?

Comment: What platform? Most IDE (if not all) have them. VS, dbx, ...

Comment: I'm using unix command line here. I can copy paste the code into Eclipse but still I don't know how to use a debugger..

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbx_%28debugger%29

Comment: Your debugger is _probably_ gdb

Comment: @slater I tried gdb but it shows no stack..

Comment: Did you compile with `-g`?

Comment: yes I did.. it produces a.out...

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> char *buff = fgets(buff, 1024, file);
>       ^^^          ^^^
> ```

You need to call `fgets` with memory that you have already allocated. Something like:

```
char buff[1024];
fgets(buff, sizeof buff, file);
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quit understand.. do I replace my original code EXACTLY with your code?

Comment: You can try. However I would refactor de program; you seem to be doing `fgets` all over the place. It would be ideal to call it from one place only.

Comment: It still gives segmentation fault. Is there anything else in my code causing this problem or is it just i'm calling fgets too many times?

Answer (score 0):

You never check if `fopen()` actually worked.

```
FILE *file=fopen(...);
if (NULL != f) {    /* If the file was actually opened */
    /* Do the work */
}
```

Also, do you really have a file named `argv[optind+i]` ? Maybe you meant to omit the quotes:

```
fopen(argv[optind+i],"r");
```

Also, it looks like you need to use `fseek()` or `rewind()` before the successive calls to `fgets()` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/.

Finally, reading from file is slow. You really should just read the file *once* in *one* place and then reuse what is then in memory.

Ok, you've fixed the file problems. Now using `gdb`, I found out that your first segmentation fault happens on line 18 in `strcmp()` because `strstr()` returns `NULL` if the sequence is not found in `buff`:

```
    if (strcmp(string, strstr(buff, string)) == 0)
        return true;
```

You need to move `strstr()` out of the parameters to `strcmp()` and check for `NULL` before passing the result to `strcmp()`. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/

Comment: Help us help you. _What_ did you do, and _what_ error did you see? Show your progress in updates to your question.

Comment: The only output is Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Comment: Ok, your program compiles with the `-g` flag. Now step through the program in `gdb` until it crashes, then you know where the symptom of your (first) problem is.